# Kendo dropdown is not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have used the following code to bind kendo dropdownlist.

```
 <input type="text" id="ddlCurrency" class="k-dropdown" name="currency" tabindex="3"
                        style="width: 80px;" />

  var ddlCurrency = $("#ddlCurrency").kendoDropDownList({
    //optionLabel: "Select Area",
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    //filter: "contains",
    dataSource: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "/DesktopModules/MyServices/API/Test"
        }
    }

}).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

this code is not working in IE 8. please help me.. how can i make this working..

Answer (score 1):

Try setting dataType to json. Some browsers may not parse the JSON response otherwise.

OLD:

```
transport: {
    read: "/DesktopModules/MyServices/API/Test"
}
```

NEW:

```
transport: {
    read: {
       url: "/DesktopModules/MyServices/API/Test",
       dataType: "json"
    }
}
```